# LINQ Where expression of unknown type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database where all tables have a primary key named `ID`.

I don't want to have to make multiple GetObjectForId for all my tables, i would like to make a generic method that takes IQueryable and a Type and then try to get an object from the IQueryable selection if possible.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Type> GetObjectForIdInCollection(IQueryable selection, Type t, int id)
{
    return selection.Cast<T>().Where(c => c.ID == id).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Obviously this code is totally wrong, but you get the idea what i'm trying to do.

Is this a good idea? How can i implement this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a base interface, which all your entities implement:

```
public interface IIdObject
{
    int Id { get; set; }    
}

// ...

public T GetObjectForIdInCollection<T>(IQueryable<T> selection, int id)
    where T : IIdObject
{
    return selection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

but I don't think it is worth the effort.

Comment: `Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()` is bad practice since it gets ALL items and then selects the first one. Simply write `FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id)`

Comment: @FredrikRedin - I'd still change because it is more readable but  performance wise there is no difference between the two.. It generates the same sql (maybe the one has a nested select but it has no influence on the performance).

Comment: @FredrikRedin Linq-methods are executed deferredly, you know? When calling `Where(...)` you don´t actually *execute*  the statement, instead you *append* some condition to it. Only when calling `Enumerator.MoveNext()` the statement and thus the database is hit.

Comment: How do i use this method? Let's say i have a method returning IQueryable<TestTable>, and i want to pass this data to GetObjectForIdInCollection? And then get a TestTable object?

Comment: @LordVermillion You simply pass your queryable to the method, which returns a `TestTable` instance or null. You could also change the method to an extension method as suggested by Slava Utesinov.

Comment: @heinzbeinz i get TestTable cannot be used as type parameter T in the generic type or method

Comment: @LordVermillion does `TestTable` implement the `IIdObject` interface (maybe `IEntity` would be much better name as otherwise suggested)?

Comment: @heinzbeinz Actually it doesn't, The TestTable class is autogenerated by Entity Framework, i don't know if it's a good idea to implement interfaces to autogenerated classes?

Comment: @LordVermillion you didn't use code first? On DB first, you could use T4 templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375682/creating-a-base-class-for-all-entities-in-entity-framework-5-in-db-first-approac

Comment: @heinzbeinz no, i'm making a Web API for databases that are already existing, so yes DB first

Comment: @LordVermillion if you can't change the class generation process via T4 templates, than I think you are stuck. All the suggestions presented here assume a common base type.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Code-First, then you can create `BaseEntity` class and derive all entities from this class.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then,

```
public T GetObjectForIdInCollection<T>(IQueryable<T> selection, int id)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    return selection.Where(c => c.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    // Or you can simply use:
    // return selection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your classes should implement `IEntity` interface, also you can use extension method:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public static class Extention
{
    public static Type GetObjectForIdInCollection<Type>(this IQueryable<Type> selection, int id)
         where Type : class, IEntity
    {
        return selection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var item = source.GetObjectForIdInCollection(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must inherit all your models from a base class (the base type BaseModel) that has ID as property, then :

```
public GetById<T>(int id, IRepository repo) where T : BaseModel
        {

                IQueryable<T> setQuery = repo.Get<T>();
                return setQuery.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id== id);
        }
```